# Debug extension pauseRequest not called

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a debugger extension. I have it to where it loads and will call evaluateRequest() when something is typed in the debug console. However, pauseRequest() does not get called when I click on the pause button.

```
class Session extends DebugSession {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.setDebuggerLinesStartAt1(false);
        this.setDebuggerColumnsStartAt1(false);
    }

    initializeRequest(resp, args) {
        resp.body.supportsDataBreakpoints = false;
        resp.body.supportsBreakpointLocationsRequest = false;

        this.sendResponse(resp);
    }

    launchRequest(resp, args) {
        console.log('launchRequest');
        this.sendResponse(resp);
    }

    pauseRequest(resp, args) {
        console.log('pauseRequest');
        this.sendResponse(resp);
    }

    evaluateRequest(resp, args, req) {
        const text = req.arguments.expression;

        console.log(`evaluateRequest ${text}`);
        this.sendResponse(resp);
    }
}

class InlineDebugAdapterFactory {
    createDebugAdapterDescriptor(_session) {
        return new vscode.DebugAdapterInlineImplementation(new Session());
    }
}

module.exports.activate = (ctx) => {
    const factory = new InlineDebugAdapterFactory();

    ctx.subscriptions.push(vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterDescriptorFactory('my-debugger', factory));
    ctx.subscriptions.push(factory);
}
```

I'm at a loss as to how to figure out why pauseRequest isn't getting called. Is there a way to have VSCode break when the pause button is hit so I can step through it?

Edit:
Apparently the pause button doesn't work until it knows about the threads from threadsRequest() being called. The only way I've found to force that to happen is by sending a StoppedEvent.

Is there no way to start the debugger in a running state?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a hack, but it works. In launchRequest(), send a stopped event without specifying a thread number. That'll force it to call threadsRequest() and the pause button starts working.